Running Ansible commands in VS Code
I am trying to integrate Terraform and Ansible.
I am working under Windows via VS Code and I have an Ubuntu running for Ansible.
So far every time I want to run the Ansible playbook or modify something, I have to open Ubuntu and modify the things there.
Is there a way to manage Ansible via VS Code under Windows while the Ubuntu is running?
Thank you in advance!

vscode has "remote" options that let you open a terminal on a VM/remote machine. Exactly how you set that up will depend on how your vm is setup, but ssh should probably work.
